# How can i calculate drag on an Angled area?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, aerodynamics, fluent, drag

I want to calculate drag force at special angle on a sphere . There are some grooves on the sphere and these groove have a special angle on the sphere. In other words, I want to calculate drag force on the these grooves. How can I do it in Fluent?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe under *Results>Reports>Forces*, you can calculate the force on a chosen surface in a particular direction vector (by providing x,y,z coordinates). Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, but how can I provide  x,y,z coordinates in Fluent?
 
Please see y-z coordinate in above picture. Therefore, direction vector is as follows:
y----> -cos teta

and
z---->-sin teta

and 

x---->0

.........teta=angle

Is it OK?

Comment: Direction of flow is in direction (or parallel) of grooves. please see second picture in above

Comment: @user19061 in the 'Force Reports' dialog box, you input what direction vector you want to calculate, then Fluent will give you the total resultant force vector, as well as the force on the chosen surface in the direction vector you specified.

Comment: @user19061 however, it might help if you could clarify further about the flow situation. Is this a full 3D model of a grooved sphere, with flow coming from the positive z direction? If so, for example, it might better to request the torque acting on the whole sphere, and the drag force acting on it.

Comment: No, Flow is coming from the negative z direction, of course with a special angle (90-theta) and with respect to z direction and yes, this is a full 3D model of a grooved sphere

Comment: If drag is a force acting opposite to the motion of Fluid, therfore, I should change direction vector as follows:

y----->+cos theta
z----->+sin theta

.....Is it correct?

Comment: In fact, Firstly, i select my surface, then, I change the  direction vector  .

Comment: So, this isn't just 2 grooves, but a series of grooves, equally-spaced around the circumference of the sphere? In that case, the angle of the groove faces will be different for each groove and, furthermore, the groove faces may not be planar, which might further complicate the situation.

Comment: Yes, You are right. this isn't just 2 grooves and yes, there are a series of grooves, equally-spaced around the circumference of the sphere. Regarding groove faces, I have doubt, I think you are right. Isn't it enough to select groove faces in Fluent and write values for y and z direction vector? should these groove faces be planar?
 Do you have any suggestion or idea that what do i do in this case?